# Flutter : No Devices available

Tags: flutter

Good night people !!!!

I am making settings in the Flutter Framework to use Android Studio, I already did a lot of the settings but when interpreting the flutter in the command line, do not find the device, so I went to look for the settings in Android Studio and gave a stop in the AVD Manager to Virtual Devices ... the error

```
   GPU#1 
   Make: 8068. 
   Model: Mobile Intel (R) 4 Series Express Chipset Family (Microsoft Corporation-WDD 1.1) 
   Device ID: 2a42
```

I ask for help solving the problem. Here is the error screenshot.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the emulator via command line/terminal/cmd.

first, find the emulator list:

```
emulator -list-avds
```

then run one of it:

```
emulator -avd avd_name -gpu mode
```

If you cant find the emulator command, try to look at the executable in 
`c:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk` then add the path to your environment.

Answer (score 0):

try running emulator from terminal, forcing it to run using hardware graphics (instead of letting emulator decide on which) using command

```
emulator -avd avd_name -gpu mode
```

where mode is host so that it will run with hardware.

example:

Using Android Studio terminal move to folder where the emulator is located. Default on Win10 is: `C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\emulator`

Find emulator to run by listing available ones: `emulator -list-avds`

Run emulator with -gpu host option: `emulator -avd avd_name -gpu host`

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the following path.

```
File > Project Structure > Project SDK
```

If there is NO SDK selected. Then Select Appropriate Android SDK by configuring it.

Otherwise,

In your terminal, add following command

```
adb kill-server

adb start-server
```

I hope this will definitely work for you.